# Can SQL be present on the same server as SharePoint 2016?

Tags: 2016, best-practices, farm-setup

I am trying to create a VM for SharePoint 2016.
Can I have both SQL and SharePoint installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes its possible to have a single server SharePoint 2016 development Farm.

The machine needs to have atleast 16 GB RAM available. The processor should be 64 bit and 4 cores. Also there needs to be 80 GB space available  for system drive and 100 GB for second drive.

Step by step guide - [Single server 2016 installation & configuration](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33907.sharepoint-server-2016-single-server-installation-configuration.aspx)

[Install SP 2016](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/page/install-sharepoint-2016.aspx#affix-2016-2)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in a development environment it's quite common.

But in acceptance test and production environment it's not recommended.

Comment: looks like we were typing at the same time :)

Comment: @GautamSheth Yep - you beat me to it though, with a few seconds :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But this is not recommended on production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it can be very hard to setup all the prerequisites correctly.

I would strongly recommend you read Sahil Malik's book [SharePoint 2013 Development Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Y4QZT8).   Although the book is a version behind, I believe you will find his advice on using an SSD, setting up Active Directory, configuring SQL for SharePoint, disabling the loopback check, setting up networking, etc. to be very helpful.